# Redmine API to fetch all issue in python

Tags: python, redmine, redmine-api, python-redmine

I am trying to fetch all the issue from redmine

```
list_1 = []
issuess = conn_red.issue.all()
for i in issuess:
    list_1.append(i)
print len(list_1)
```

The print statement result is 575

But In Redmine, I have 2735 issue.
I wonder,

1. why it is restricting to 575.
2. Its there any limitation in number of count
3. Any other possible way to fetch all record

Comment: Why not read from redmine db directly ?

Comment: I am organize a CRON job for openerp, so sync is the better option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the REST API only returns open issues. If you want to get all issues, you have to define a filter:

```
issues = conn_red.issue.filter(status_id='*')
```

Please refer to the [documentation of python-redmine](http://python-redmine.readthedocs.io/resources/issue.html#filter) as well as the [API documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues) of Redmine itself.

Comment: Is `.all` a typo for `.all()`, or is that how it's called after using `.filter()`?

Comment: Meh, too much Ruby lately :)

Comment: Haha, I feel you. Whenever I switch between Python, LUA, Javascript and PHP my syntax gets scrambled for days.

Comment: issues = conn_red.issue.filter(status_id='*') which return the entire issue in the redmine, No need to add the all() at the end. Thanks for your idea

Comment: saved my evening. that's missing in their doc (or I din't see it)